# Cake PHP not building Models

Tags: cakephp

I have created my database, and used `cake bake my_project` to create my project, and now when I try `cake bake all` form within my project directory, I get an error relating to Mysql. When I view my project from the browser, it all lights up green, including connecting to the database.

```
Warning Error: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in [/Users/billy/Documents/projects/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 160]
```

Any ideas as to what this error is about?

---

***EDIT**: Added relevant configuration details (php --info |grep mysql)*

I don't really know what to look for in here, but maybe someone does...

```
$ php --info |grep mysql
Configure Command =>  '/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/php/configure'  '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--sysconfdir=/private/etc' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--enable-cli' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl=/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/Root/usr/local' '--with-png-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-53.3.1~2/Root/usr/local' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-ldap=/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-iodbc=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'
mysql
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off
mysqli
Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqlnd
mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
pdo_mysql
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

---

Edit: More info

I tried the suggestion from @0k32, but unfortunately it did not work for me. I soft linked php from my XAMPP folder to `/usr/bin/php`, and checked it was the right one with `which php`. I then did a `php --info | grep sock` and got:

```
MYSQL_SOCKET => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Which seems to suggest that the correct version of MySQL is being activated. Still I am getting exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue could appear because of different configuration files (php.ini) used by apache's php module and command line php. Default settings for mysql connections may differ in those configs.
Compare `phpinfo()` output from apache and `php --info` from command line.

**Update:**

In your case it seems you are on MacOS and are using MAMP/MAMP PRO. So am I. And I had the same problem.
My solution was very simple. I replaced default php cli binary with a symlink to MAMP's php binary:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php_default
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

MAMP's php is connecting to MySQL via `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` by default and MacOS's default command line php is trying to use `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Anyway I think it's a good practice to use the same php with the same config for both web and cli.

**update:**

A smarter solution would be not to replace default php but just add path to MAMP's php binaries to the `PATH`. So in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin:$PATH
```

Correct it if needed.
Then reopen terminal or execute this: `source ~/.bash_profile`. Then you can check which php you are using by executing `which php`. It should point to MAMP's php.

Comment: I solved this before getting your answer by installing a ubuntu server in a virtual machine, but I would prefer to get things working like you have. I will give this a go. Thanks ,~)

Comment: I am using XAMPP, I don't know what MAMP is, but I am assuming a Mac version of XAMPP which I use because it is cros platform.